# MySQL IF in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three MySQL InnoDB tables:
Debtors
Companies
Private individuals

Now I would like to find information about a debtor.
The following SQL is not working, can anyone help me with writing working SQL?

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.type,
    i.name
FROM
    debtors AS d
IF d.type = 'c' THEN
    INNER JOIN
        companies AS i ON (i.debtor_id = d.id)
ELSE THEN
    INNER JOIN
        private_individuals AS i ON (i.debtor_id = d.id)
WHERE
    d.id = 1
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF d.type = 'c' THEN INNER JOIN companies AS i ON (i.debtor_id = d.i' at line 7
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried hunting for `IF` in the MySQL documentation? E.g. find the right syntax for `IF`? You're trying to do stuff that's not doable in MySQL (possibly on SQL altogether).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would usually accomplish something like that:

```
SELECT d.id, d.type, COALESCE(c.name, p.name)
FROM debtors d
LEFT JOIN companies c
  ON d.type = 'c' AND c.debtor_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN private_individuals p
  ON d.type = 'p' AND p.debtor_id = d.id
WHERE d.id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I've used!

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `IF` like that!

Here is a possible solution:

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.type,
    COALESCE(i.name, i2.name) as name
FROM
    debtors AS d
    LEFT JOIN companies AS i ON i.debtor_id = d.id and d.type = 'c'
    LEFT JOIN private_individuals AS i2 ON i2.debtor_id = d.id and d.type <> 'c'
WHERE
    d.id = 1
```

---

Another might be Dynamic SQL but you should avoid it! :)

Comment: Two usual solutions are a `LEFT JOIN` just like in your example and a `UNION` which is bad from performance side. The third option is a subquery. Not pretty, definitely not as fast as a `LEFT JOIN` but works within an `IF`. +1 for the proper solution.